# jquery use zclip copy text disable alert

Tags: jquery

I want to  disable using `jquery`  the alert of `zclip` when text copied using zclip
this code works fine but i want to disable the alert!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("button.copy-javadomain").zclip ({

    path : "ZeroClipboard.swf",

        copy : function() {
            return $("input.ifram").val();
                         }

              });
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Comment out the line:

```
alert("Copied text to clipboard:\n\n " + text);
```

in **jquery.zclip.js**

or use **`afterCopy`** Callback function

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("button.copy-javadomain").zclip ({

    path : "ZeroClipboard.swf",

    copy : function() {
        return $("input.ifram").val();
                     },
    afterCopy:function(){
     //leave it blank to override the default alert message
            }

          });
      });
```

http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/ --- Ref Link

Comment: @ZouaouiDjaballah cheers . Kindly upvote and accept the answer if you are satisfied